MongoDB lookup issues
I was trying to use the aggregate function of the MongoDB
Post.findSingleById = function(id) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof(id) !== 'string' || !ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
            reject("Invalid ID format");
            return;
        }

        try {
            let posts = await postsCollection.aggregate([
                { $match: { _id: new ObjectId(id) } },
                { 
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "users", 
                        localField: "author", 
                        foreignField: "_id", 
                        as: "authorDocument"
                    }
                }
            ]).toArray();
            
            if (posts.length) {
                resolve(posts[0]);
            } else {
                reject("Post not found");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};

this was my code and the issue that I am facing is I don't get why my authorDocument is returning an empty array instead of returning the User object, this is what my console looks like after execution of this code :
db connected...
listening on 8000...
post {
  _id: new ObjectId('671f72ae91ccf544bb88477a'),        
  title: 'Post by Hrishi',
  body: '1st post by me',
  createdDate: 2024-10-28T11:17:02.856Z,
  author: new ObjectId('671f72ae91ccf544bb884779'),     
  authorDocument: []
}

I tried things where I found that the match property wasn't able to detect the matching id and that's why it was returning me an empty authorDocument which should contain the details of the User like name, email, password, etc. but I didn't get why that was happening, I would be glad if someone could help me with this and feel free to ask any other bits of code if you want to debug the problem properly.

Start by manually verifying if the _id ObjectId('671f72ae91ccf544bb884779') is in the users collection. Also verify that it's an actual ObjectId in users and not just the string '671f72ae91ccf544bb884779'. Also check the collection name users is correct. If all this is true, then your aggregation would be working: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mVYFmKfyi65

Hey I did the parts the collection name users is correct and also the it is a ObjectId and not a string, I am posting my entire code on github so that you could analyze things completely link, I still don't get where the issue lies

We're not going to a full review your entire code base. As my mongo playground example shows, your query is correct. So your data is wrong, or your collection names are wrong, or your field names are wrong. Voting to close this question. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.
